# integrate inequality with $f(a)=f'(a)=\cdots =0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

if $f\in C^{n+1}[a,b]$ and $f(a)=f'(a)=\cdots =f^{(n)}(a)=0 $ prove that $\forall 1\le p<\infty$ we have

$\left(\int_a^b\mid f(x)\mid^p dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\le \frac{(b-a)^{n+\frac{1}{p}}}{n!(np+1)^{\frac{1}{p}}}\int_a^b\mid f^{(n+1)}(x)\mid dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Taylor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) applied to $f$ with the Lagrange remainder we see that
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{n!}\int_a^x(x-t)^{n}f^{(n+1)}(t)\,dt.
$$
Then
$$
|f(x)|\le\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}\int_a^x|f^{(n+1)}(t)|\,dt.
$$
All is left is to take the $p$-th power of both sides and integrate between $a$ and $b$.